# Files count check (SAS)

Tags: sas

can I ask is there a simple way to perform a files check.

I have a dataset call DPS_file_count, which I read in from the directory:

DPS_cais_DPSCAIS_Interactive_Workbook_20230629.xlsm
DPS_cais_DPSCAIS_Summary_Workbook_20230629.xlsm

the purpose of this check is to see whether the files in the directory has been outputted correctly. In this example DPS_cais is the output_name macro variable which I created based on the input name. We should expect to see three file outputted for each output name

DPS_cais_DPSCAIS_Interactive_Workbook_20230629.xlsm
DPS_cais_DPSCAIS_Summary_Workbook_20230629.xlsm
DPS_cais_DPSCAISappend_20230629.csv

```
data check_filenames;
set DPS_FILE_COUNT;
flag = filename;
do until (flag = filename or eof);
set DPS_FILE_COUNT end = eof;
if filename = "&output_name._DPSCAIS_Interactive_Workbook_&date..xlsm"
or filename = "&output_name.DPSCAISappend_&date..csv"
or filename = "&output_name._DPSCAIS_Summary_Report_&date..xlsx" then flag = 1;
end;
run;
``




/*check what files is missing*/
PROC SQL;
create table file_compare as 
SELECT b.filename from check_filenames b
where filename not in (select filename from dps_file_count a where a.filename = b.filename);
quit;



PROC SQL;
create table COUNT_FILES AS SELECT COUNT(filename) AS COUNTS  FROM file_compare
;



DATA CHECK_NUM_FILES;
SET file_compare;
IF COUNTS >= 1 THEN FILE_COUNT = "FAIL" ;ELSE FILE_COUNT = "PASS";



So the purpose of the checks is to identify if the correct number of  excel files has been outputted in the folder.
The output name always changes depending on the input name. I’ve already built this macro variable in so that it scan the input name. For every input name e.g. A we expect to see three files outputted
The only thing that changes is the macro variable output name and date . If there is two Input file with input name A&B we should see six files. However, I'm struggling to execute the logic behind the code as it’s currently not take into account of the missing file 



    data _null_;
  set DPS_FILE_COUNT end=eof;
  retain flag 0;
  if filename in
     ("DPS_cais_DPSCAIS_Interactive_Workbook_&date..xlsm"
      "DPS_cais_DPSCAIS_append_&date..csv"
      "DPS_cais_DPSCAIS_Summary_Report_&date..xlsx"
     ) then flag+1
  ;
  if eof then do;
    put 'NOTE: Found ' flag "files for &date..";
    call symputx('nfiles',flag);
  end;
run;

%put NOTE: Found &nfiles files for &date.. ;
```

Comment: If you want to know which file is missing do you have a list of the files that should be there?

Comment: Yeah these should be the files:
filename=“&output_name._DPSCAIS_Interactive_Workbook_&date..xlsm"
filename = "&output_name.DPSCAISappend_&date..csv"
filename = "&output_name._DPSCAIS_Summary_Report_&date..xlsx"

However in the file directory it only contain these two files :
DPS_cais_DPSCAIS_Interactive_Workbook_20230629.xlsm DPS_cais_DPSCAIS_Summary_Workbook_20230629.xlsm

Comment: The output_name changes base on the input file name so it will always output 3 excel files. The check is to make sure that it satisfy the above condition and flag as pass or fail in the output check

Comment: If the constant text in your code (things like _DPSCAIS_Interactive_Workbook_ and DPSCAISappend_) is in fact not constant then you need to provide more an better examples of the files in your directory.  Preferable for use in the example shorter names that make the variations in the patterns clearer.

Comment: How do you know which dates need to be checked?  Or is it the case that if at least one 'dated' file exists there should be three? (And thus, ignoring the case when all three files are missing for a given date)

Comment: Hi Richard, it’s the output name that I’m looking out for. For instance a file name testing, I should be expecting to see three csv output with the name testing

Comment: The three filenames you started with are not CSV files. You keep moving the goal posts.  If there is no pattern at all there is no way to make a program.  The only thing you seem to have that seems constant is that 8 digit date string suffix on the filename.  So just count how many files per date suffix there are and if it is not a multiple of three then there is a missing file.

Comment: yes, what I'm thinking is creating a loop that loop over the output name which takes the input file name and create a table with 3 filename per input name like outname_DPSCAIS_Interactive_Workbook_date.xlsm
outname_DPSCAIS_summary_Workbook_date.xlsx 
outname.DPSCAISappend_date.csv 
and then compare to the files in my directory if that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like there is a pattern the filenames based on that 8 digit date suffix.

If you already have that in a macro variable named DATE then just use that to test if the files exist or not.  No need to actually make your list of filenames.

```
data check ;
     length filename $200 ;
     do filename="DPSCAIS_Interactive_Workbook_&date..xlsm"
                ,"DPSCAISappend_&date..csv"
                ,"DPSCAIS_Summary_Report_&date..xlsx" 
     ;
       filename=cats("&output_name._",filename);
       flag = fileexist(filename);
       output;
     end;
run;
```

The result will be a dataset with three observations. The missing ones are those where FLAG is false.

If you don't know the 8 digit suffixes in advance then extract them from the list of files.  Say you have a dataset with FILES with variable names FILENAME you can make a dataset named DATES with a list of all of the distinct 8 digit suffixes in a variable names DATE with an SQL query like this:

```
proc sql;
create table DATES as 
  select distinct scan(scan(filename,-2,'.'),-1,'_') as DATE
  from FILES
;
quit;
```

You can then use that to drive a similar data step to generate three filenames for each DATE value.

```
data check;
  set dates;
  filename = "&output_name._DPSCAIS_Interactive_Workbook_", date , ".xlsm";
  output;
  filename = "&output_name._DPSCAISappend__", date , ".csv";
  output;
  filename = "&output_name._DPSCAIS_Summary_Report__", date , ".xlsx";
  output;
run;
```

Which you can then merge with the original list of filenames.

```
data check;
  merge check(in=in1) file(in=in2);
  by filename;
  exists = in1 and in2;
  missing = in1 and not in2;
  extra = in2 and not in1 ;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tom. Yes, the date will always be the same as it indicate when the file was outputted. The filename will always be the same except for the date and output_name. I've already implemented the macro variable so it will scan the input filename to get the output name.

would something like this work? say if i have multiple input file with filename test1 and test2 so i should be expecting 6 files.

```
data check_filenames;
set DPS_FILE_COUNT;
retain flag 0; /* Initialize flag to 0 */

    
    /* Check if the filename matches all conditions */
    if filename in 
        ("&output_name._DPSCAIS_Interactive_Workbook_&date..xlsm" 
        "&output_name.DPSCAIS_append_&date..csv" 
        "&output_name._DPSCAIS_Summary_Report_&date..xlsx" )
    if eof then do;
put 'NOTE: Found ' flag "files for &date..";
call symputx('nfiles',flag);
```

end;
run;

Comment: i'm trying to loop this so that if filename matches what's in the directory then flag as pass or fail. say for instance, the directory has these four files which are missing 1 file based on the output_name

DPS_cais_DPSCAIS_Interactive_Workbook_20230629.xlsm DPS_cais_DPSCAIS_Summary_Workbook_20230629.xlsm

Comment: DPS_test_DPSCAISappend_20230629.csv

Comment: DPS_test_Summary_Workbook_20230629.csv